# ENOENT: no such file or directory (using Multer)

Tags: node.js, multer

I am getting a "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'devfront/public/uploads/image-1609664873651.jpg'" The folder 'devfront/public/uploads' is available as shown here in my file directory for the project: [image: file directory], the public folder is the public folder that came from creat-react-app.

Here is my code for my backend to handler the file upload with the help of the multer library:

```
import path from 'path';
import express from 'express';
import multer from 'multer';
const router = express.Router();

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, './devfront/public/uploads/');
  },
  filename(req, file, cb) {
    cb(
      null,
      `${file.fieldname}-${Date.now()}${path.extname(file.originalname)}`
    );
  },
});

function checkFileType(file, cb) {
  const filetypes = /jpg|jpeg|png/;
  const extname = filetypes.test(path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase());
  const mimetype = filetypes.test(file.mimetype);

  if (extname && mimetype) {
    return cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb('Images only please...');
  }
}

const upload = multer({
  storage,
  fileFilter: function (req, file, cb) {
    checkFileType(file, cb);
  },
});

router.post('/', upload.single('image'), (req, res) => {
  res.send(`/${req.file.path}`);
});

export default router;
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: In your backend try this `console.log(path.resolve('./devfront/public/uploads/')` i think all you need is two dots before `/devfront/public/uploads/` --> `../devfront/public/uploads/`

Answer (score 1):

you can access your folder from root directory of your project.

```
const path = require('path');
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, path.join(__dirname, './devfront/public/uploads'));
  },
  filename(req, file, cb) {
    cb(
      null,
      `${file.fieldname}-${Date.now()}${path.extname(file.originalname)}`
    );
  },
});
```

Comment: Accessing the folder from the root directory of the project via `path.join(__dirname, '<relative-folder-path>`) worked for me

Answer (score 0):

This will also happen if you have forbidden chars in the file name, eg if you have ":" in the filename on Windows, etc.